# puppeteer evaluate results in context destroyed

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, jestjs, puppeteer

Trying to wait for DOM mutations to stop but ends with `Execution context was destroyed.`, any suggestion is welcome

```
            page.evaluate(() => {

                return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

                    var timerId;

                    function resetTimer() {
                        clearInterval(timerId);
                        timerId = setTimeout(() => {
                            resolve(true);
                        }, 3000)
                    }

                    new MutationObserver(
                        () => {
                            resetTimer();
                        }
                    ).observe(document.getElementById('root'), {
                        attributes: true, childList: true
                    });

                    resetTimer();

                })
            })
        })
```

Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Execution context was destroyed. undefined

```
  at Promise (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:198:56)
  at CDPSession.send (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:197:12)
  at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:71:75)
  at ExecutionContext.evaluate (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:46:31)
  at Frame.evaluate (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:299:20)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above snippet was run before getting a navigating lock on a page. Running the `page.evaluate` between navigation can throw this error.

Found this from,

1. [Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Execution context was destroyed.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1591)
2. [No page navigation lock ?](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/823)

Fix was (at least in my case) to wait till URL changed and then `page.evaluate`.

Comment: I added an `await page.waitForSelector('#my-selector')` and it worked properly!  Nice point.

Answer (score 1):

Notes:

- Are you using async/await in your code? If you have a promise but don't use any chain or async/await, then it should throw up errors like that.
- Also you are firing the resetTimer out of observer callback too.
- If not, then you are probably not monitoring the correct changes of that dom element.

Here is a a simple react app which changes state after 2 seconds.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { bar: "foo" };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ bar: "not foo" }), 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="App">{this.state.bar}</div>;
  }
}
```

Here is the modified code for the above snippet.

```
 await page.evaluate(() => { // wait for it to resolve
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var timerId;

      function resetTimer() {
        clearInterval(timerId);
        timerId = setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(true);
        }, 5000); // resolves after some time
      }
      const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
        // show me the changes
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            console.log(mutation.type);
        });
        // reset timer etc.
        resetTimer();
      });

      // observe a lot of changes
      observer.observe(document.getElementById("root"), {
        attributes: true,
        characterData: true,
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
        attributeOldValue: true,
        characterDataOldValue: true
      });
    });
  });
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: thanks for help but the fix was to get a navigation lock on a page before page.evaluate, running it between navigations resulted in the said error